# Audio starts to periodically skip

Tags: windows-xp, audio

My audio starts to periodically skip. Sometimes it starts after one day, sometimes after a few days. When it skips, the audio, and the application playing it ([Winamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winamp), [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube), [MPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer), etc), hangs for about 20 ms and resumes.

The skipping is always at regular intervals, sometimes as close as 2 s apart, sometimes as much as 4 seconds in between.

While in this state, when I record audio with a recording program, it occasionally, but randomly, hangs for more than a whole second, and then it shows to have recorded that amount of time as silence.

This problem only started recently after I re-installed Windows (from the same CD no less).

The only solutions I've found is rebooting or going into and out of stand-by.

I already have the newest audio driver, which is a horribly old driver because DELL dropped the Windows XP support for my four-years-old laptop. It's a "Sigmatel High Definition Audio" device (I cannot find a type number).

Comment: Your motherboard might be dying because you are killing it with XP

Comment: At least it's killing it more softly than if I would've used Windows 7.

Comment: Not really. XP wasn't as memory efficient as 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DPC Latency checker](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) according to its instructions to find the faulty driver.

It will show the skips as high red peaks on a moving bar chart. Keep disabling drivers and potentially services until the high peaks are gone.

Comment: I've already tried killing processes until there is no process left anymore that will not kill windows when killed. I could start stopping services but with the amount of services active, I hoped for a faster solution, like finding out which application is the one hanging. The description on the DSP checker site looks helpful.

Comment: It's most likely driver issue since it causes hangs on your compputer - so it's important to disable devices (drivers) and not processes. Some services also tie into drivers so they could also be at fault though. One service I know for sure has a problem is the HP Power Assistant latest version. AFAIK it causes severe stuttering every 30 seconds on all HP laptops running that version...

Comment: It finally happened to me again. It took more than a month, the longest time I've seen so far. This tool worked, although I didn't strictly need it as I can hear the skips in the audio. After spending 30 minutes disabling/enabling service and devices, it turned out to be either of my network adapters. Re-enabling didn't bring the glitch back. Thanks.